# Android (Xamarin) Using Manifest File

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

Android documentation (such as https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) suggests that all Activities need to be declared in the manifest XML file.

Although I have used this file for permissions, I have so far not entered any Activity details.  I do however have a preprocessing directive in the class source file for each Activity such as

**[Activity(Theme = "@style/AppFullScreenTheme", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, NoHistory = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher")]**

Is it mandatory to add Activity details to the manifest ?

- If so, why have I not run into any issues so far.
- If not, are there any disadvantages in not adding Activity settings
  to the manifest.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#The_Basics), the activities are added automatically to your manifest by Xamarin when you use the preprocessing directive. So your activities are actually defined in the manifest when Xamarin builds the app.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  My question really regards the fact that the AndroidManifest.xml file in the Visual Studio project is never updated by the build process.  Where does the information get stored (if at all)?

Comment: When Xamarin builds, it will probably copy the manifest and add all the activities to this copy. It will then use the copied manifest to build the app. After building that copy will be deleted. I don't know if it's exactly like this, but the process will be similar.

Comment: Thanks @Jesse Hoobergs

Comment: @MHugh, the auto-generated manifest file ends up in the project obj folder under say Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml or something like that